# How does shared_ptr call the right destructor when make_shared is used to construct it?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived : Base {};

std::shared_ptr<Base> sp(new Derived);
```

So the explanation is that sp knows that it needs to call the destructor of Derived because Derived argument was passed in the constructor. However in this case of creating a shared pointer with make_shared you don't supply the pointer, and so it can't know the Derived type. Does this mean that the correct behaviour of having a shared_ptr pointing to a Derived can only work in the case of supplying your own pointer to the constructor, not in make_shared?

Comment: `make_shared<Derived>` is the only way to create `Derived` with `make_shared`. The type is right there.

Comment: @StoryTeller So then does the assignment operator needs to be templated to accept a = shared_ptr<Derived>? As in shared_ptr<Base> sp = make_shared<Derived>();

Comment: That's a converting constructor there, but yes. Both are templates (constrained on pointer convertibility).

Comment: Related, I love seeing people's minds blown when they discover that `std::shared_ptr<void> sp = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();` does the right thing, regardless of where `sp` eventually ends up. And, based on the OP's title, that may have even been a better example.

Comment: @WhozCraig So shared_ptr stores a function ptr the deleter?

Comment: I don't believe the internal mechanics of how it does it are specified in the standard. But, that's how every implementation I've ever peeled the layers back on does it. Unlike unique_ptr, the deleter of a shared pointer is always established at construction-time, not declaration time. I always thought it interesting that shared_ptr doesn't have a template-argument provision for a deleter type, while unique_ptr does. Then... I saw `std::share_ptr<void>` and thought 'wow; didn't see that coming'.

Comment: @Zebrafish You can see some of the typical intrinsics listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr#Implementation_notes)

Answer (score 0):

[`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) "knows" which destructor to call because the type of the originally owned object is recorded at the point of `shared_ptr` construction.

In the case of constructing `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> sp(new Derived);
```

`shared_ptr` constructor internally creates an object that, among other things, stores the original pointer to `Derived` and an associated deleter that will be called on the pointer when the last `shared_ptr` referencing that object is destroyed. This internal pointer to `Derived` is separate from the pointer that is exposed through `shared_ptr` interface methods, such as `get` or `operator->`, and it stays intact for the whole lifetime of the referenced `Derived` object. The exposed pointer may change by constructing different `shared_ptr` instances, and in some cases may not even point to the `Derived` object at all. This is why although `std::shared_ptr<Base>` exposes the pointer to `Base`, it is still able to destroy the original `Derived` in the end.

The case with `make_shared` is similar:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> sp = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

Here, `Derived` object creation and `shared_ptr` initialization happens within `make_shared`. Simplistically, you could think of `make_shared` like this:

```
template< typename T >
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared()
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> internal_sp(new T());
    return internal_sp;
}
```

(I'm intentionally simplifying `make_shared` implementation here.)

So, in `make_shared`, when `internal_sp` is initialized, it records the object type with the associated deleter just as explained above. When `sp` is initialized from the result of `make_shared`, it simply inherits the deleter and the original pointer, and converts the exposed pointer from `Derived*` to `Base*`.

This feature of `shared_ptr` is key to its many other useful capabilities, such as:

- Hiding the deleter type from the `shared_ptr` type. For example, `shared_ptr<FILE> spf(fopen("foo.txt", "r"), &fclose)`.
- Flexibility in pointer conversions. For example, as noted in the comments, `shared_ptr<void> spv = sp` is valid, and `spv` will still be able to destroy `Derived` object as expected.
- Pointer aliasing, when the exposed pointer is pointing to a different object than the one that was originally allocated. Usually, this is used when the lifetime of the pointed object is limited by the lifetime of the allocated object (e.g. the pointed object is a data member of the allocated object).
- Partly, the fact that the allocated pointer and deleter are stored in a separate object, is useful for supporting [`weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), as it allows to store reference counters in that object as well.